# Prevent overwriting a file with redirection

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

if I do:

```
$ node foo.js > output.d.ts
```

is there a way to configure the shell to do not overwrite the file if it already exists? Maybe a no-clobber option?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using the bash shell thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is there a way to configure the shell to do not overwrite the file if it already exists? Maybe a no-clobber option?

Yes, there is [the `noclobber` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> Prevent output redirection using `>`, `>&`, and `<>` from overwriting existing files.

```
$ echo foo > bar
$ echo foo > bar
$ set -o noclobber
$ echo foo > bar
bash: bar: cannot overwrite existing file
```